# three.js how to change camera up vector?

Tags: javascript, three.js

In three.js I have camera point somewhere using camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0). Afterwards camera.up vector is basically in random direction. I have a known up vector where I want the camera's up to be but when I set it it doesn't do anything:

```
camera.position.set(0, 0, 5);  // works
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);        // works
camera.up.set(1, 0, 0);        // nothing
camera.up.set(-1, 0, 0);       // nothing
camera.up.set(0, 1, 0);        // nothing
camera.up.set(0, -1, 0);       // nothing
camera.up.set(0, 0, 1);        // nothing
camera.up.set(0, 0, -1);       // nothing
```

How to change camera's up vector? camera.rotateZ(0.1) works but I don't know how much to rotate, I would just like to use up vector.

Comment: Have you seen this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506425/three-js-how-do-up-vectors-work-with-lookat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`up` is only used when you call `lookAt`. `lookAt` is not a state, it's a funciton that sets `rotation` for you. So if you change `up` you need to call `lookAt` again.

```
camera.position.set(0, 0, 5);  // 
camera.up.set(1, 0, 0);        // set up
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);        // now call lookAt
```